# Tensorflow Serving Fails if a new request comes before previous computation is finished

Tags: python, load-balancing, gunicorn, tensorflow-serving

I currently have a web api run using flask, gunicorn, and nginx, the web api calls my tensorflow model serving port. When the web api is called multiple times before the first is finished the tensorflow model fails gives an empty request.

What is the best way to handle this? My web api is currently already behind gunicorn and nginx, but the calls from the api to the tensorflow model seems to be the problem. Should I put it behind gunicorn / nginx load balancer as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Use several workers. Each gunicorn worker will load a model. This must be done on start, because it takes some time to load a model. Workers can handle several petitions.
2. Use a [state machine](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions): idle, processing. You will raise exceptions if a you receive a GET when processing and raise 503 Service Unavailable.

Comment: my server has a 4 core cpu already setup with 4 GUnicorn workers. Will the workers interfere if I setup tf model serving with another 4 GUnicorn workers?

Comment: Each worker will rn in parallel, so you can handle simultaneous requests that use the model.

Comment: Actually the problem I think is when multiple instances of tensorflow-model-serving starts running which crashes the process because of the amount of CPU and ram it takes. If anything I should be putting tensorflow-model-serving behind a queue. Will something like redis queue work for that? I know tensorflow-model-serving is based on gRPC but i;m not too familiar with this

Comment: is it possible to get celery to block tasks instead of having to poll for the status?

Comment: nvm, I just read up, the .get() seems to give me what a want, sorry for that. I'll give this a try, been stuck on this for a while...

Comment: @ackbar03, what is this .get()?